# NSDictonary set value for key in for loop Get last value only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to pass the parameters to server the parameters are in one array like 
parameters1 (2,3,5,7,9,16,25) i want to pass

```
@"tags[]" : @"2"
@"tags[]" : @"4"
```

.........

```
 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject: userId forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters setObject: userToken forKey:@"token"];
for (i = 0 ; i < parameters1.count   ; i++) {

 [parameters setObject:[parameters1 objectAtIndex:i]forKey:@"tags[]"];

}
```

I am getting the output as

```
 @"user_id" : 2

  @"token" : khsskjkjwllwklkllk

  @"tags[]" : 25
```

here i want to pass all the tags but i am getting only last tages value only

i want to add the tags from an parameters Dictonary.

Comment: Use parameters1 to NSMutableArray and try.

Comment: and also share whole your code.

Comment: allocate the dictionary inside the loop[

Comment: Try my below answer, just add two more lines.
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
and Inside for loop, [arr addObject:parameters];

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can only hold **one value per key**, so:

```
[parameters setObject:[parameters1 objectAtIndex:i]forKey:@"tags[]"];
```

Always sets `parameters1[i]` as the (string) value for `@"tags[]"`.

Perhaps you intended to use an array as the value for that key?  I can't say, but if so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
parameters[@"user_id"] = userId;
parameters[@"token"] = userToken;
parameters[@"tags[]"] = parameters1;
```

Comment: @"tags[]" = is a text type nsstring

Comment: @user3518202 Oh well.  It can only have one value regardless.

Comment: for (i = 0 ; i < parameters1.count   ; i++) {
 parameters[@"tags[]"] = parameters1[i];
 }  I am geting the last value in array  so please guide me.

Comment: I want to add all values from array to parameters dictionary and hit server.

Comment: @user3518202 Well you haven't described how that works, but anyway I have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can direct add array of  parameters1 for "tag[]".

Comment: No the tag[] is of text type

Comment: NSArray *parameters1 = @[@"2",@"3",@"5",@"25"];


[parameters setObject:parameters1 forKey:@"tags[]"];


while fetching
NSArray *parameters1=[parameters objectForKey:@"tags[]"];

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your code,

```
NSMutableArray *parameters1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2",@"3",@"5",@"7",@"9",@"16",@"25", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i = 0 ; i < parameters1.count   ; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *parametersTag = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parametersTag setObject:[parameters1 objectAtIndex:i]forKey:@"tags[]"];
    [parameters1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:parametersTag];
}
[parameters setObject: @"111" forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters1 addObject:parameters];
[parameters2 setObject: @"dhfjkhds" forKey:@"token"];
[parameters1 addObject:parameters2];

NSLog(@"arr : %@",parameters1);
```

It will generate output as below,

```
(
    {
    "tags[]" = 2;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 3;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 5;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 7;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 9;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 16;
},
    {
    "tags[]" = 25;
},
    {
    "user_id" = 111;
},
    {
    token = dhfjkhds;
}
```

)

Comment: Why not just use `parameters1` as the value?  What's the value of creating a new array and copying its contents?

Comment: As per his question, parameters1 is an array of tags, parameters1 (2,3,5,7,9,16,25)

Comment: But `parameters1` is already an array so why not use it in its current form?  Why make a copy of it?

Comment: I think you can get clear idea from above answer, just added output.

Comment: Hi i want to add each element in an parameters1 array to key @"tags[]": value

Comment: Alright. Actually I am not getting exact idea what do you want? But just edited my answer. Let me know either it works for you or not?

Comment: i want to get out put as below    "tags[]" = 25; "tags[]" = 2; "tags[]" = 4; "tags[]" = 9; "tags[]" = 20;
        token = dhfjkhds;
        "user_id" = 111;
    } help me.

Comment: Hey I am just going to update my answer. I know it's bit wired. But It will produce the output same as you want. Let me post it as another solution.

Answer (score 0):

As `NSDictionary` can hold only one value for each key you have to differentiate your key with any extra number or character.

Here you are using key tags[] which can hold last set value.

I have update your code with one small change which can change your key and hold each value

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject: userId forKey:@"user_id"];
[parameters setObject: userToken forKey:@"token"];
for (i = 0 ; i < parameters1.count   ; i++) {
    [parameters setObject:[parameters1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat@"tags[%d]",i]];
}
```

Your will get output as

```
@"user_id" : 2
@"token" : khsskjkjwllwklkllk
@"tags[0]" : 2
@"tags[1]" : 3
@"tags[2]" : 5
@"tags[3]" : 7
@"tags[4]" : 9
@"tags[5]" : 16
@"tags[6]" : 25
```

I hope you understand the answer.